# Specific index of Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

So I'll give you some brief background, I'm in AP computer science and I'm confused on this program.

We are suppose to enter in the size of the array, then the program runs through a for loop, get the full name in one string, ( use `scanner.nextLine();`), then the test Score, which isn't that important. The user then will enter the first name of ANYONE and there should be a for loop running through each array seeing if firstName is in the first name array.
The problem is firstName when is printed out is blank.. fixed the first error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class totalScores {
public static void main(String[]args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
int sizeOfArray = input.nextInt();
String kline[] = new String[sizeOfArray];
for ( int index= 0; index< kline.length; index++)
{
System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
String name = input.next();
kline[index]= name;
input.nextLine();
}
double[] testScore= new double[sizeOfArray];
for (int i = 0; i< testScore.length; i++)
{
System.out.println("enter the test score");
double testz = input.nextDouble();
testScore[i]= testz;
input.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Enter first name : ");
String want = input.next();
for( int index = 0; index < kline.length; index++)
{ 
String firstName="";
String namez;
namez = kline[index];
int space = namez.indexOf("");
firstName = namez.substring(0,space);
if (want.equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))
{
  System.out.println("The test score is: "+ testScore[index]);
}
else
{
System.exit(0);  
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: The code looks correct to me.

Comment: Kindly post the complete stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not too clear but I can see the for loop is running with kline.length as the limit, but you are getting nameofarray[index] which could be an array with different size than kline.

Comment: Sorry I meant (nameofarray)[index] is kline, I had to retype it several times and I forgot to change that.

Comment: In that case, maybe your namez doesn't have a blank, space will be -1 and an outOfBoundsException will be generated when trying to execute substring(0, space)

Comment: the error was a double space in the indexOf method. It should be indexOf(""); but now firstName is blank after running the compiled program ( when it prints out)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem is here:

```
int space = namez.indexOf(" ");
```

In case the `namez` don't contain spaces in it, the value for `space` will be `-1`. So it will form this statement:

```
namez.substring(0, -1)
```

Of-course you will encounter exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
String firstName = kline[index].split(" ")[0];  
System.out.println(firstName);
```

This will return the first word of `kline[index]` even if it doesn't contain a space.

The error is occurring most likely because your `kline[index]` does not contain a space (therefore, `indexOf(" ")` returns -1. And you **cant** substring with `(0,-1)`